# Modify Notification.Builder progressbar without custom layout

Tags: android, notifications

Does anybody know how I can use the Notification.builder and then subsequently update the progress bar? Currently it appears restricted. I understand that I can access notification.contentView but updating the progressView from here requires the view ID which is part of the android internal class (which I don't have the scope to access). Surely if the notification builder allows you to display a progress bar there should be a way to update it?

I should add that I'm hoping to do this without repeated calls to 'getNotification' as this seems incredibly inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a new Thread to do that in a dirty way. However, by this way, your notification will not go to an end, until it goes over itself.
Here is the code.

```
public void showJobFinishNotification() {
    final String ns = Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE;
    final NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(ns);
    final Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, WillingActivity.class);
    final PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
    final int JOBFINISH_ID = 1;

    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for(int progress = 0; progress <= 29; progress++) {
                Notification jobFinishNotification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplication())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher) //must have small icon, but the large icon is not a must
                    .setContentTitle("Job is finished")
                    .setContentText("Press here to finish your job.")
                    .setProgress(29, progress, false) 
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND)
                    .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setAutoCancel(false)
                    .build();
                notificationManager.notify(JOBFINISH_ID, jobFinishNotification);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            notificationManager.cancel(JOBFINISH_ID); //if you want the user to handle the notification.
            //comment the line above. and use setAutoCancel(true) in the above code.
        }
    }).start();
}
```